# List of ListItemCollection

Tags: c#, list

Can I make a list of ListItemCollection?. I am trying to improve the loading time from my code because I load each ListItemCollection separately.

```
 ListItemCollection items;

 foreach (PublishedProject proj in projects)
 {
        items = list.GetItems(qry);

        spClientCtx.Load(items);
        spClientCtx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

I want it to be something like that.

```
 ListItemCollection items;
 List allItems;

 foreach (PublishedProject proj in projects)
 {
        items = list.GetItems(qry);
        allItems.Add(items);

 }
 spClientCtx.Load(allItems);
 spClientCtx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Is this possible or is there even an better way to do that so I only need 1 "ExecuteQuery()";

Comment: where is `proj` used inside the `foreach`

Comment: not that important I deleted most of  the code to simplify it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a List of ListItemCollection

```
List<ListItemCollection> l = new List<ListItemCollection>();
```

Comment: You're welcome ! maybe mark the question as answered :D

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it can be done, it should work like this

```
 ListItemCollection items;
 List<ListItemCollection> allItems = new List<ListItemCollection>();

 foreach (PublishedProject proj in projects)
 {

        items = list.GetItems(proj);
        allItems.Add(items);

 }
 spClientCtx.Load(allItems);
 spClientCtx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: If I do it like That it doesn't work because `allItems` is an array but if i do it like that: `allItems[0]`. I get the exemption   "The request uses too many resources."